# The norm of linear functional $x\mapsto \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{2^n}$ on $c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Consider the mapping $\phi :c_0 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{2^n}$. Compute $\|\phi\|$ Does there exist a $x \in c_0$ such that $\|x\|=1$ and $\|\phi\|=|\phi(x)|$

Clearly $\|\phi\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1} |\phi(x)|=\sup_{\|x\|=1} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{2^n} \leq \sup_{\|x\|=1} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}=1$

Now from above we have that $\|\phi\|\leq 1$ and as $x \in c_0$ we can choose $x_n=1$ for n as large as we want and get |$\phi(x)|$ as close as we want to $1$ . But then since $\lim_{n \to  \infty} x_n=0$ , it is impossible that

$\|x\|=1$ and $\|\phi\|=|\phi(x)|$

Question:Does my argument make sense and if yes how could I write it down more rigorously?

Edit : I am sorry, I was sloppy. $c_0=\{\text{Space of all sequences whose limit goes to zero}\}$ and I am using the $\infty- norm$

Comment: Quick question, what's $c_0$ and what norm are you using on it?

Comment: Yes, your argument makes sense. Pick $\varepsilon > 0$. What does $\lim x_n = 0$ then mean? Use that to write up your argument rigorously.

Comment: @avid19 I am sorry, I was sloppy. $c_0=\{\text{Space of all sequences whose limit goes to zero}\}$ and I am using the $\infty norm$

Comment: If you want it more rigorous: For $n$ sufficiently large, you have $|x_n| < \frac{1}{2}$ and thus $|\phi(x)| < 1 = \|\phi\|$.

Comment: @user251257 That part is clear. I am more concerned with my first non-rigorous argument which somehow concludes that $\|\phi\|=1$

Comment: For each $n$ consider the sequence $x^n_1 = \dotsb = x^n_n = 1, x^n_{n+1} = ... = 0$. They yield $\phi(x^n) \to 1$.

Comment: The question is reasonably well written but the title was _horrible_. Looking at "Am I on the right track?" it's impossible to figure out whether this is a question of interest to me or not.

Comment: @NormalHuman You are right, I would be careful next time. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is right. To express it more rigorously, you can do something like this: for every $\|x\|<1$, 
$$  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{2^n} < \sup_{\|x\|=1} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}=1$$
where the inequality is strict because $x_n\le 1$ for all $n$ **and** $x_n<1$ for some $n$.

On the other hand, the vector $x = (1,\dots,1,0,\dots)$ with $N$ ones has $  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{2^n} = 1-2^{-N}$, which can be arbitrarily close to zero.

Together, the above paragraphs show  that the norm is $1$ and it is not attained.